# Issue while calculating float value using NodeJS N-API

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-napi

Hello everyone,

Coming from the web dev world. I am currently trying to do some C code which is converting an RGB value to an XYZ value that can be used by NodeJS through N-API. The issue that I have is regarding to **float calculation**. Below is the explanation of my issue:

Based on this C code below, this code is trying to convert an RGB value to an XYZ value.

```
char * colorType = getStringValue(env, funcParams[2], SPACELen);
// m is either the value srgb | adobeRgb
Matrix m = getEnumFromStr(colorType);
Rgb * rgb = getRGBFromJSObj(env, funcParams[0]);
xyz = generateXyzFromRgb(rgb, m);
```

And I am using this JS snippet to call my library

```
const rgb = {
  r: 255,
  g: 255,
  b: 255
};

const xyz = lib.getXyzFromRgb(rgb, "srgb", 10000);
expect(xyz).to.be.deep.equal({
  x: 0.9504,
  y: 1,
  z: 1.0888
});
```

If everything should be all right the output should be like the one below

```
{
 x: 0.9504,
 y: 1,
 z: 1.0888 
}
```

However the output that I have is this one

```
{
 x: 0.9502,
 y: 0.9997,
 z: 1.0886 
}
```

As you can see the output is totally wrong. **However this wrong output only happened on my local machine (OSX) and only when I am trying to do the conversion by using the JS snippet.**

Indeed, when I am trying to run the conversion with this piece of code below directly through Xcode the **output is correct**

```
// RGB and & m variable is outputing the same value as the conversion done by the C code above
xyz = generateXyzFromRgb(rgb, m);
```

Moreover when I'm trying to call the **JS code through travis which also running OSX and on Ubuntu through Docker the JS code also output the right value**.

Can it be more related to the hardware or the way I am compiling my libraries or else ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the numeric data types in the C code?

Comment: Also in general in any programming language where numbers are binary floating-point values, performing strict equality tests is tricky.

Comment: @Pointy the numeric data type is float. Should i change this to double ?. Indeed I looked at the IEE754 which looks to be tricky... However I find it strange that the wrong output only happened on my machine and only when using the JS snippet and not on travis osx or a in ubuntu

Comment: The C `float` type is (usually) only 32 bits; JavaScript numbers are 64 bits.

Comment: @Pointy Hmm yes, behind the usage of the float value I am converting the float to the double value in order for the value to be used by N-API. Do you think that there might be a loss of precision during this conversion ? I guess I should try to convert it right away into double and see how it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript v8 engine. Actually only exist smi and double.
readFloatBE: when float pass to v8, the float will be cast to double.
it will promote to the double when you go out and rounding into a float.

First, if you really want to get value like C, you need to manually specify the rounded digits and re-instantiate the Number object with the Number.prototype.toPrecision function rounded up:

For your reference:

```
var v = 5.2
var buffer = new Buffer(5)
buffer.writeFloatBE(v)
var g = buffer.readFloatBE()

console.log(v)
console.log(g)
console.log(v==g)
console.log(Number(g.toPrecision(5)))
```

Comment: Hmm indeed. I could return a buffer instead of a float value that might help in term of precision

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as post by [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) and [user10683038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10683038/user10683038) JavaScript numbers are 64 bits.

As I coded this feature the numeric type used was float (was not thinking at making a Node module at first glance). Later on I decided to do a conversion from **float to double** using a small util method like below

```
double v = *(double *) arg;
status = napi_create_double(env, v, &value);
```

**Strangely** it appear that I might have **randomly loosing decimal precision** while doing this conversion while it should have not (32bit to 64bit) or I might have missing out something.

Later on I refactor the same code but this time by **using double** instead and it works as it should. Many thanks to all of you.

**Note**: As I used this util code above method accross the NodeJS binding codebase I am surprised that I haven't got a decimal precision error earlier.